# Setting a type of data that gets returned from a fetch function to match a custom type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've got these two interfaces in my app:

```
export interface Job {
    job_title: string,
    employer: string,
    responsibilities: string[]
    achievements: string[],
    start_date: string,
    end_date: string
}

export interface CreatedJob extends Job {
    job_id: string,
    user_id: string
}
```

I'm trying to use them to make my setState and useEffects type safe, by following this principle:

```
// First, I fetch my jobs from my database using react-query.
    const { isLoading, data } = useQuery(['jobs', user.id], () => fetchJobs(user_id))

// I then define a state array, which will be updated inside of an effect once the data has run.
    const [array, setArray] = useState<CreatedJob[]>([])

    // Inside of the effect, I check if the data exists, and if so, to set my array with 'data' inside of the returned data.
    useEffect(() => {
        if (data) {
            setArray(data.data) // For reference, this is where I'm getting the error.
            console.log(data);
        }
    }, [data])
```

I'm getting the following error inside of the setArray call in my useEffect:

> Argument of type '{ [x: string]: any; }[]' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'SetStateAction<CreatedJob[]>'.   Type '{ [x:
> string]: any; }[]' is not assignable to type 'CreatedJob[]'.
> Type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'CreatedJob': job_id, user_id, job_title, employer, and 4
> more.

Essentially, I think it's trying to tell me that the 'data' returned doesn't match the correct type - but it clearly does, as I can map through the data in my return statement, using the 'CreatedJob' type no problem:

```
{ array.map((job: CreatedJob, index) => {
                return (
                    // Returns content perfectly in here
            })}
```

Just for reference, this is the 'fetchJobs' function which fetches the data - I use Supabase for the BE:

```
const fetchJobs = async (user_id: string) => {
        const { data, error } = await supabase.from("jobs").select("*").eq("user_id", user_id)

        return { data, error }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that typescript can't get the `data.data` type because you didn't specify that.
You should set a type in fetchJobs:

```
const fetchJobs = async (user_id: string) => {
  // CreatedJob passed to supabase
  const { data, error } = await supabase.from<CreatedJob>("jobs").select("*").eq("user_id", user_id)
  return { data, error }
}
```

By passing a type to `supabase.from` you specify the type of the `jobs` table.
Now the type of `data` is `CreatedJob`, and the return type of the `fetchJobs` is `{ data: CreatedJob, ... }`.
In the `useEffect` of the final component we should have the correct type